# ArcFM geodatabase with ArcGIS Mobile

Tags: arcgis-server, arcfm

I understand that if ArcFM Object Viewer is installed on ArcGIS Server that read-only map services can be published with the ArcFM data.  In this scenario can you also publish ArcGIS Mobile applications from Server?  If so, does the ArcFM Object Viewer need to be installed on the mobile device with ArcGIS Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

I would say Yes, because ArcGIS would not be able to understand ArcFM objects at any point, and would require ArcFM Object Viewer.